# git diff shows nothing

Tags: git, git-diff, git-stash

After I do a `git reset --hard HEAD`, I do a `git status` and everything is clean.  Then I do a `git checkout stash@{0} -- pom.xml` to get the pom.xml file in the stash.  When I do a `git status` it shows `modified:  pom.xml`.  When I do a `git diff`, it shows nothing.   Why?

Comment: Because your change is already staged. Check `git diff --staged`

Comment: Please can you click [edit] and show the exact output of `git status`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of (1) what `git diff` means, and (2) what a stash is. With a little bit of (3) what `git status` tells you, thrown in.

Let's start with the second one. A stash is two commits, one representing the index, the other representing the working tree. Checking a file out of the stash thus affects both the index and the working tree.

Now then. `git diff` plain and simple (no modifiers) asks: how does the working tree differ from the index. In this regard it does *not* differ and so no output is shown. You have the same modified version of this file in both the index and the working tree, which is good — you are ready to commit, if that's what you want to do. If your question was how the index differs from the HEAD, you should have asked `git diff --staged` instead.

Finally, `git status` does *two* comparisons, unlike simple `git diff`: it compares the working tree with the index to tell you what modification is / is not added to the index, and it compares the index with HEAD to tell you what making a commit now would do.

So the sum total is this:

```
HEAD    index    working tree
-----------------------------
 old     new         new
```

That is the situation reflected by the answers to the questions you've asked Git (`git diff` and `git status`).

To put it another way: what `git status` tells you is what you would learn by asking *both* `git diff --staged` *and* `git diff`. But you never asked `git diff --staged` so you don't see that part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because git added changes to staging step.

You can restore staged changes:

```
git restore --staged pom.xml
git diff
```